# Django URL Dispatcher variable number of components

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

Essentially I have a single view that accepts different operations and a varying number of parameters. This was previously working in the following state:

```
url(r'^items/(?P<op>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', login_required(ItemOpView.as_view()), name='my.views.item_op'),
```

Which always provides `kwargs['op']` and `kwargs['id']` to the view. This allows for URLs such as:

- items/delete/1
- items/show/1
- items/hide/1

However I'd like to adapt the rule to also accept the following:

- items/relocate/1/2 meaning I'd like to have `kwargs['id2']` as well.

I've attempted to do this with the rule:

```
url(r'^items/(?P<op>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(?P<id>[0-9]+)(?/)(?P<id2>[0-9]+)$', login_required(ItemOpView.as_view()), name='my.views.item_op'),
```

However this doesn't work and just gives a 404.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another url entry like so:

```
url(r'^items/(?P<op>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/(?P<id2>[0-9]+)$', login_required(ItemOpView.as_view()), name='my.views.item_op')
```

And make sure your view accepts a default parameter (like `None`) for the second parameter.

Comment: Ahh I realized that I could probably do this right after I posted :) Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Dont forget to close the question if it worked for you.

Comment: Good answer +1. I would only add that make sure you the patterns are in the right order.

Comment: You answered too quickly! Had to wait, but thanks for the reminder.